# Python bokeh Google Maps plot - show 1km distance based on zoom on bottom right

Tags: python, google-maps, bokeh

If I use Google Maps in web browser then the "base" distance is shown based on zoom level on the bottom right part of the map. It looks like something like this: "1km |___________|" where the distance value can be eg. "100m, 200m, 500m, 1km, 2km, 5km...", and the length of "|___|" can be different based on zoom level.

How can I display the same when I generate a bokeh Google Maps plot?
On bokeh Google Maps plots there are only the "Map data ©2016 Google" and "Terms of Use" and "Report a map error" strings on the bottom right part but no distance metric.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.3`, this is not exposed as an option. Enabling this will required new development. I have made a feature request issue on GitHub that you can track:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5442

However, if you have the experience and ability to work on it we'd be happy to help you get started with Bokeh development. Given the current issue backlog and resource constraints, a new contribution from a motivated new contributor is almost certainly the fastest path to having it accomplished.